# ComboBox Datasource giving exception

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, combobox

I have this simple piece of code for populating a `ComboBox` :

```
 DataSet dt = new DataSet();

 dt = db.getCourses(depID, academicYearValue, semID);
 if (dt.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
 {
     dropdownCourses.DataSource = dt.Tables[0];
     dropdownCourses.DisplayMember = "Course";
     dropdownCourses.ValueMember = "ID";
 }
```

I have  4 `ComboBoxes` on the Form all work with the code above and get populated, only for this `ComboBox` when populating `DataSouce` i get exception :

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

And i cannot figure out anything , any suggestions what to look for?

Comment: Probably it's null when you are assigning

Comment: The Table has Rows in it approx 48 i confirmed that. It will enter the loop when  if (dt.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0) so it has something..

Comment: add a condition if(dt.Tables.count > 0)

Comment: @Sajeetharan is  it not automatically confirming dt.Tables.count > 0) if it confirms dt.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0

Comment: Object References Not Set.... [is well explained here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it). Just start up your debugger and you will find out.

Comment: @Steve  that is the issue i am debugging i see the Data in datatable and still i get the error above. Same piece of code on 4 other comboboxes working fine.

Comment: Using the debugger will tell you the line that triggers the exception, hovering with the mouse over the elements involved will tell you which one is the null one. Keep in mind that the acting of assigning a property could trigger an event where the error kicks.

Comment: This is the line with the error :   dropdownCourses.DataSource = dt.Tables[0];  and the element involved here is Dt which i see is not null. So why the exception.

Comment: and `dropdownCourses` ?

Comment: @Steve dropdownCourses is a comboBox

Comment: @Steve , You were rite i mistakenly do dropdownCourse=null somewhere in the code which was causing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility when you have handled `SelectedIndexChanged` or `SelectedValueChanged` or any other event. That will be called when you set the `DataSource` property of your combobox.

This happens because `ValueMember` is not set when `DataSource` is being assigned. Suppose you have written a line of code in the `SelectedValueChanged` event of your combobox like this.

```
 String myVal = dropdownCourses.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

Here, I am trying to convert `SelectedValue` into string type value.

This code will get executed immediately after assigning `DataSource` of Combobox and before assigning `ValueMember` property. So, that means the combobox doesn't have the `ValueMember` field.

So, the value in `SelectedValue` property will be `null` and `null` cannot have any property or method where we are trying to convert it into string. So, this will throw the error `object reference of instance of an object is not set`.

**Solution:**

You should set the `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember` properties before assigning `DataSource` to the ComboBox.

```
dropdownCourses.ValueMember = "ID"; //First
dropdownCourses.DisplayMember = "Course";  //Second
dropdownCourses.DataSource = dt.Tables[0]; //Third
```

The second way is that you can create a boolean flag to avoid the unnecessary event call during the populating combobox.

```
bool bLoading = false;

{
    dt = db.getCourses(depID, academicYearValue, semID);
    if (dt.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        bLoading = true;
        try
        {
            dropdownCourses.DataSource = dt.Tables[0];
            dropdownCourses.DisplayMember = "Course";
            dropdownCourses.ValueMember = "ID";
        }
        catch{}
        finally{
            bLoading = false; //make sure that this variable must be false after populating combobox otherwise event will not work
        }
    }
}

private void dropdownCourses_SelectedValueChanged(....)
{
    if (!bLoading)
    {
        Write your code here.
    }
}
```

I would like to suggest second option if you don't want to call event unnecessarily.